# Deep linking to open MS Teams chat with Guest user (different domain)

Tags: microsoft-teams, deep-linking

I am using this URL to create a deep link to open a chat in MS Teams app to an guest user. The same is working for an internal user i.e. same domain as I am currently in. But does not work for guests added in a Team with a different domain.

msteams:/l/chat/0/0?users=John.Doe@outsidedomain.com

e.g. works when user is internal, does not work when user is from another domain, although he is added in a team as guest.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try with https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=John.Doe@outsidedomain.com . It works fine in web and desktop versions and there was a [bug](https://domoreexp.visualstudio.com/MSTeams/_workitems/edit/1670720) in mobile version in your use case.

Comment: no longer works on web or desktop, only on mobile.